# Definition of linear dependence

Tags: linear-algebra, definition

My linear algebra teacher stated the following definition:

> Let $V$ be a vector space and $v_1,...,v_n \in V$ vectors. We say that $v_1,...,v_n$ are linearly dependent if $\exists \alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ not all $0$ such that:
> $$\sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_kv_k = 0$$

The part that is confusing me is: "$\exists \alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$ not all $0$". Does this mean that, if at least 2 vectors are linearly dependent, then the whole set of vectors is said to be linearly dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if a subset of vectors is linearly dependent, then the set itself is dependent. The proof is simply - take your equation with some non zero scalars, and add whatever vectors you want multiplied by $0$.

The converse is not true. If a set is linearly dependent, it is possible that all its subsets are independent (think of $\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$).